# Why is auto-white balance shifted red after an unfortunate camera drop?

Tags: white-balance, equipment-damage, fujifilm

My camera bag was open on a chair, chair got bumped, camera came tumbling out — about 18" onto a wood floor. Ouch! PC sync terminal cover somehow popped off and went flying to who knows where. Everything else appears fine — except, immediately when I took a test shot I discovered that everything is *pink*. If I set a custom white balance (either manually or with a preset), it's fine.

The camera is going to go to Fujifilm (it's an X-T2) for repair and a check of the lens that was attached for my peace of mind, but I'm puzzled — what possible damage could be causing this?

Comment: What does the color look like in the EVF when the WB is set to Auto? Are you testing under the same lighting conditions that were used the last time you used AWB *before* the camera was dropped?

Comment: Pink in the EVF, on the rear LCD, and in the results. Was immediately apparent indoors under incandescents, and I then went outside to check under sunlight — same results.

Comment: But were you shooting under some funky green lighting (like some kinds of fluorescents) that would have caused the camera to shift everything towards pink to correct for it the last time you used AWB before the drop?

Comment: Ah, I see what you are getting at. It was in a restaurant back room, so it was dim incandescent lighting.

Comment: No idea then. My thinking was that with custom WB and presets the processor just converts the raw data based on known values. With AWB the processor must analyze the scene, decide what it thinks is white (usually the brightest parts of the scene), and then assign and apply a WB. If a ribbon cable or other electrical connection has become loose that prevents the processor from getting that data (maybe from a dedicated WB analysis chip or a memory chip that stores a library of WB scenarios) then I was thinking it might default to the last used value.

Comment: For anyone following the scintillating details of this case, repair estimate is $150 for the lens check and $170 for the body, so I guess they think it's probably nothing big — we'll see if there's a helpful explanation of what they found after they do the work.

Comment: I've never used Fuji factory service. But if they are anything like Canon unless there is obvious external damage (say, a cracked front lens element) the initial estimate is nearly always the minimum charge before they open it up and find what's wrong and needs to be replaced.

Comment: Yeah, it does say "Fujifilm reserves the right to revise the original Service Repair Estimate if additional and/or hidden internal damage is discovered." I'll keep you updated.

Comment: Also, annoyingly, they did not email or call, but rather mailed a response, which I did not get until because I was traveling for the holidays. Good thing I still have my X-T10 as backup.

Comment: So, for what it's worth — they fixed it for the above price with a few pennies, and the only comment is "Camera checks to within factory specs". I guess we'll never know.

Comment: Are you just now getting it back?

Comment: No; got it back a long time ago but forgot to update as I'd promised.

Answer (score 2):

Some cameras utilise an external light sensor to measure the light that falls on the camera and use the data from that sensor to adjust white balance in auto mode.  Manual adjustments override this sensor, so my guess is that this sensor got broken. Everithing else about auto WB happens on software level as far as I know so that is my only guess.